# Button Changes color after i click somewhere else

Tags: knockout.js

I have a Yes and a no button, I added some simple CSS to it that when the user clicks the button should change green and when the user clicks no the button changes red, but if i click yes an then click somewhere else on the page, like a blank spot then only the color changes to green, I am using knockout JS
Here is my html:

```
                        <div class="controls col-md-6">
                        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" style="background-color:inherit">
                            <label class="yes btn btn-default active-green" data-bind="click: SetAttended,css:{ active: EditView.koModel.SampledIndividualViewModel.HasAttended() === true, background-color: 'green'}  ">
                                <input class="yesno" type="radio" value="Yes" id="btnYes" /> Yes
                            </label>
                            <label class="no btn btn-default active-red active" data-bind="click: SetAttended, css:{ active: EditView.koModel.SampledIndividualViewModel.HasAttended() === false, background-color: 'red'} ">
                                <input class="yesno" type="radio" value="No" id="btnNo" /> No
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

and here is my js:

```
  that.SetAttended = function (data, event) {
                    if (event.target.classList.contains('yes')) {
                        data.EditView.koModel.SampledIndividualViewModel.HasAttended(true);
                    }
                    else if (event.target.classList.contains('no')) {
                        data.EditView.koModel.SampledIndividualViewModel.HasAttended(false);
                    }
                    else {
                        data.EditView.koModel.SampledIndividualViewModel.HasAttended(null);
                    }
                };
```

Comment: i guess checking `.classList.contains('yes')` is wrong as its "yesno" in both cases, you rather want to check the value attribute yes/no

Comment: Could you make a fiddle?